# Error in PORTB pic18f2550

Tags: pic, assembly, port

I've read most of the datasheet, but have not found a solution. Why is PORTB on my PIC18F2550 only accepting a maximum value 3? My code is:

```
;Configure PORTA e PORTB
MOVLW   0x0F ; Configure A/D 
MOVWF   ADCON1 ; for digital inputs

;Enable the pull-up resistor
MOVLW   0X00
MOVWF   INTCON2

;Set all the pins of TRISB as input, except for <R0:R1> that are outputs
MOVLW   b'11111100'
MOVWF   TRISB

;Clean up registers
CLRF    LATB
CLRF    PORTB
```

The LATB can store 11111111, but only stores 00000011 PORTB, why?

Comment: Do you have anything connected to PB[2:7]?

Comment: Actually 0:1 function as output and the remainder as input. See the figure (http://imageshack.com/a/img802/2199/ozsv.png). Remembering that I enabled the pull-up resistors internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the posted code, it seems you only "half-enabled" pullups by clearing INTCON2[!RBPU].  To really enable them, you also have to set the corresponding LATB bits.

From the [pic18f2550 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf):

> RBPU: PORTB Pull-up Enable bit
>         1 = All PORTB pull-ups are disabled
>         0 = PORTB pull-ups are enabled by individual port latch values

In your code you cleared LATB, effectively disabling the pullups.

Comment: Even enabling RBPU with 0, with only 2 bits to set mode debugger. See figure!
http://imageshack.us/f/36/izhd.png/

Comment: @RonaldAraújo The image in your previous comment contains "MOVWF RBPU" in the code, which makes no sense to me.  It should be something like "bcf INTCON2,RBPU" to enable pullups.